# How to install pgperl for postgresql 9.6 windows

Tags: postgresql, windows, perl

Trying various versions of ActiveState and Strawberry Perl, I'm still not having any luck overcoming:

```
pg96/lib/postgresql/plperl.dll:  The specified module could not be found
```

Suggestions that may have worked for prior versions of postgres don't work for 9.6

Comment: Are you sure that the .dll is part of the perl install, not part of either the PostgreSQL install or (more likely) a separate module you'd get from CPAN?

Comment: @RDFozz : I do actually have the file plperl.dll - it seems it may be missing dependencies. I downloaded dependencywalker and plperl.dll has a dependency on perl520.dll which is all in good order (nothing is missing in the whole dependency tree) ... but there is a whole whack of sub-dependencies missing under postgres.exe, kernel32.dll and msvcrt.dll (to long to list)

Comment: You could try registering the .DLL, or making sure that its path is included in your PATH environment variable. Not sure either would help, just a thought.